# Is it possible to rent camping tent in the Iya Valley or Yagen Valley, Japan?

Tags: budget, japan, camping, rental, hiking

I'm thinking about spending couple of days hiking in Iya Valley, Shikoku or Yagen Valley, Honshu.

I've read that there are awesome places for camping in which you can have a patch of grass for ¥500. Unfortunately, I won't have any equipment with me so my question is: is it possible to rent a tent in place or somewhere in the nearby cities (better if on the route of a JR train)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, here [is a website](http://www.camp-a.jp/camp/index.html) that lets you search camp sites across Japan.

Regarding the two places you mentioned, a quick search resulted in this one:

There is a [camping site in Iya Valley](http://iyakei-camp.jp/) that lets you stay in a group hut or rent a tent. Here is their [pricing list](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http://iyakei-camp.jp/ryoukinn.html).

There seems to be only one camp ground in Yagen Valley, and it does not offer rentals.
I also tried to find rental tents (テントのレンタル) in Mutsu city but could not find any.

Comment: I didn't find anything cause I didn't know how to query google in japanese :-) takes for the awesomes hints